# DotCover shows 0% for virtual method mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using DotCover to check the unit test Coverage. Inside one of the method I return results from active directory in SearchResult however, I mocked the class but DotCover displays 0%

```
public virtual T SearchOneRecord(ISearchConfigurator configurator)
    {
        var record = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        var searchResult = configurator.DirectorySearcher.FindOne();
        if (searchResult != null)
        {
            AssignActiveDirectoryValue(searchResult, record);
        }

        return record;
    }

[Test]
    public void SearchOneRecord()
    {
        //Arrange
        var configuratorMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISearchConfigurator>();
        var searchMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Searcher<NativeDs>>();
        searchMock.Replay();

        var nativeDs = new NativeDs() { PasswordAge = 100 };
        searchMock.Expect(x => x.SearchOneRecord(configuratorMock)).Return(nativeDs);

        //Act
        var record = searchMock.SearchOneRecord(configuratorMock);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(nativeDs.PasswordAge, record.PasswordAge);
    }
```

The test passes but since I'm new to RhinoMock (mocking in general) maybe there is an issue .

Any idea?

Comment: Umm, I'm afraid some coverage percentage has a zero value either way. "100%" doesn't mean you test for everything important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but what you did here is defined mock and then tested if this mock works correctly? I don't think that's something you wanted to achieve. And of course it causes test to pass - mock is working correctly, but it is not testing you application code at all - hence 0% coverage.

What you want to do probably is to mock `ISearchConfigurator` instance and then pass that mock to method as a parameter.

```
[Test]
public void SearchOneRecord()
{
    //Arrange
    var configuratorMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISearchConfigurator>();
    var directorySearcherMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDirectorySearcher>(); // please note I don't know exact type, so you need to ammend it
    var returnValue = ... // initialize with types you expect DirectorySearcher to return
    var searcher = new Searcher(); // initialize class you actually want to test
    configurationMock.Replay();

    configurationMock.Expect(x => x.DirectorySearcher).Return(directorySearcherMock);
    directorySearcher.Expect(x => x.FindOne()).Return(returnValue);
    searchMock.Expect(x => x.SearchOneRecord(configuratorMock)).Return(nativeDs);

    //Act
    var record = searcher.SearchOneRecord(configuratorMock);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(nativeDs.PasswordAge, record.PasswordAge);
}
```

Please note that I'm currently unable to test this code, but it should give you some directions into how it is supposed to be done.